# Magento 2 : add custom class on checkout page shipping address field

Tags: magento2, checkout, class

I am using magento 2.1.7. I want to add one class in country select box on checkout page shipping address.

If anyone knows please help to add class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i am also finding a better solution for this i try to add from xml but i will not add a aditional class through xml can any one let me know that why we can not add the classes ussing checkout_index_index.xml file ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create plugin after Attribute merge method. Then you can modify checkout fields and add class to wrapper of country select box.

In your module create `MODULE/NAME/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
    <type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
        <plugin name="customAttributeMerger" type="\MODULE\NAME\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in `\MODULE\NAME\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace MODULE\NAME\Model\Plugin;

class AttributeMergerPlugin
{
    public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('country_id', $result)) {
            $result['country_id']['additionalClasses'] = 'your_custom_class';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

For safety clear cache and you should see this class in div wrapper of country select.

Then you can use `.your_custom_class select` in css/less or `$('.your_custom_class').find('select');` in jQuery. Remember that JS script you have to execute when fields are generated

Comment: can you call custom attribute?
 $customAttributeCode = 'test';
'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,

in my case 'test'

Comment: hm, here is not adding custom attribute. It is only custom class for existing attirubte

Answer (score 0):

override **magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/select.html** into your theme in 
**VENDOR/THEME_NAME//Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/select.html**

```
<select class="select your_class" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label',
    optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
        if (item && item.disabled) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {attr: {disabled: true}}, item);
        }
    }"
/>
```

> Remove var/view_preprocessed
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean