# Magento 2: Zip Validation on Checkout Page

Tags: magento2

I want to add zip validation on my checkout page like right now if somebody put zip code like *6722 the order place I want some validation for special characters.

Comment: what is format support?

Comment: how i check where i can check this?@Amit Bera

Answer (score 0):

There two files you need to create.

- First,Add additional CSS class to **Postcode**  using plugin  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205672/4564

  ```
  namespace MODULE\NAME\Model\Plugin;

  class AttributeMergerPlugin
  {
      public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
      {
          if (array_key_exists('postcode', $result)) {
              $result['postcode']['additionalClasses'] = 'your_css_custom_class';
          }

          return $result;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Second, create a custom validation rule for javascript:** 
  Link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192407/4564

file code: `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'your_css_custom_class',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```